# Trying to use raw socket in Python 3 to blindly send an IP package, But keep getting ARP lookups how to disable

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to send an IP package in Python 3 on a point to point network IE Host and Client are connected directly to each other with static IP.

I'm using the following code:

```
import socket

class Client:

    def __init__(self):
        self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
        self._sock.bind(('192.168.1.10',0))

    def send(self, data):
        data_to_send = bytes([0x0,0x1C,0x23,0x17,0x4A,0xCB,0x00,0x50,0xB6,0x0D,0x35,0x9F,0x08,0x00,0x45,0x00,0x00,0x2E,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x00,0x40,0x00,0xB7,0x6A,0xC0,0xA8,0x01,0x0A,0xC0,0xA8,0x01,0x0B,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00])
        self._sock.sendto(data_to_send, ('192.168.1.11', 0))
```

However every time I try and send the package I always get ARP lookups (and the package never gets transmittet).

```
1   0.000000    GoodWayI_0d:35:9f   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 192.168.1.11? Tell 192.168.1.10
2   0.981801    GoodWayI_0d:35:9f   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 192.168.1.11? Tell 192.168.1.10
3   1.981830    GoodWayI_0d:35:9f   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 192.168.1.11? Tell 192.168.1.10
```

How do I avoid these lookups and just send the package blindly ?

It seems my search fu is broken because I cant find much documentation on Python 3 Sockets.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get around this issue by adding the IP/MAC to the ARP list

using

```
netsh interface ip add neighbors "Ethernet 3" "192.168.1.11" "00-1C-23-17-4A-CB"
```

However I would like to be able to switch it off in python

regards